# PHP ORM "Spot" throws exception for an easy use case

Tags: php, orm

I just tyed out the ORM "Spot" and created a simple entity with only 1 field, created the correspoding table and followed the documentation to insert a row for an instance of that entity. I keep getting an ArgumentCountError in the set function of the Entity class of Spot, but the Entity gets saved anyway. This is the Code im using.

```
    $data = [
        'firstName' => $this->request->getParameter('fname'),
        'lastName' => $this->request->getParameter('lname'),
    ];

    $cfg = new \Spot\Config();
    // MySQL
    $cfg->addConnection('mysql', 'mysql://TestUser:1234@localhost/bookstore');

    $spot = new \Spot\Locator($cfg);

    $userMapper = $spot->mapper('Example\Models\User');

    $entity = $userMapper->build([
        'firstName' => $data['firstName']
    ]);

    $result = $userMapper->insert($entity);
```

and the Entity:

```
class User extends Entity
{
    protected static $table = 'user';

    public static function fields()
    {
        return [
            'firstName'=> ['type' => 'string']
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: I take it your error is in the Mapper class then? Where is the set method being called? Did you pass a key and value? It sounds like you are missing an argument somewhere

Comment: Check what your Mapper passes, here is what Spot wants https://github.com/spotorm/spot2/blob/master/lib/Entity.php#L483

Comment: Okay thanks, I will look for a php debugging solution for windows.

Comment: I take it you wrote the user mapper? Can we see it?

Comment: No Spot uses a generic mapper if you dont specify one and i didnt specify/ create a mapper for the user entity.

Comment: It looks like you can customise your own mapper https://github.com/spotorm/spot2/blob/master/lib/Locator.php#L49, here's the docs for doing so http://phpdatamapper.com/docs/mappers/

Comment: So do you recommend to implement a custom mapper for every entity?

Comment: It really depends on your use case, the docs mentioned which cases they'd be suitable for